# Recursively calculate total value of current row using previous row value SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, sql-server-2014

Assuming I have a table like this

```
 Id     Initial Value    CardCount  Total
 1      5                1          null
 1      0                2          null
 1      0                4          null
 2      10               0          null
 2      0                3          null
 2      0                1          null
```

And I want to update the total column to be the sum of the "total" value of the previous row + the current row's cardCount.  For the first record in each Id, the total is the InitialValue + CardCount.  I want the result to be like this:

```
 Id     Initial Value    CardCount  Total
 1      5                1          6
 1      0                2          8
 1      0                4          12
 2      10               0          10
 2      0                3          13
 2      0                1          14
```

I have tried this but it does not produce the correct result

```
declare @tmp Table(Id int, InitialValue int, CardCount int, total int null)
Insert into @tmp values (1, 5, 1, null)
Insert into @tmp values (1,  0, 2, null)
Insert into @tmp values (1,  0, 4, null)
Insert into @tmp values (2, 10, 0, null)
Insert into @tmp values (2,  0, 3, null)
Insert into @tmp values (2,  0, 1, null)

Update @tmp Set Total = InitialValue + CardCount

;with TmpTb as(
select 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) RNum, * 
From 
    @tmp)

update c set Total= x.Total + CardCount
from TmpTb c join
(select a.RNum, a.ID, b.Total
From TmpTb a LEFT JOIN TmpTb b on a.RNum=b.RNum+1
where a.ID=b.ID )x on c.RNum>=x.RNum AND c.ID=x.ID

select * from @tmp
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? And do you have any column to order by that isn't ambiguous? Ordering by `id` won't be deterministic and thus can't be used to order rows with certainty.

Comment: I'm using SQL 2014.  Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: Ok, that leaves the second question. How would I know that id=1 cardcount=1 should come before id=1 cardcount=2? Is there some other column that determines the order of rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use recursion for this if you are using a modern version of SQL Server that can do aggregation as window functions. Then you can do `sum()` as a window function:

```
update t1 set total = y.total
from (select *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) from @tmp) t1
join (
  select id, rn, sum(initialvalue+cardcount) over (partition by id order by rn) as total
  from (select *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) from @tmp) x
) y
on t1.rn = y.rn
```

With your sample data the result would be:

```
id  initialvalue    CardCount   total
1   5               1           6
1   0               2           8
1   0               4           12
2   10              0           10
2   0               3           13
2   0               1           14
```

**This might work - or it might not.** This code relies on the server returning the rows in the same order every time which isn't something you can rely on, but as your data doesn't seem to have anything to determine the order this might be the best you can expect. If you want to produce a running total you really need a stable attribute to order the data by in a deterministic fashion.

**The main point is that if you can't order the data you can't achieve what you want with certainty.**

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you.  The table shown here is just a simplified version of my actual table so yes, I can order the data.

Comment: If you have something to order/partition the data by the the whole row_number in the derived tables can probably be removed.